# In Compositor, is it possible to change multiple node values simultaneously even though there is no input socket?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

In Compositor, some nodes do not have input socket for that value. Can I change these values at once?

[image: Compositor Node Group]

For example, my node group has *Distance* input socket. I want to use this value to *Distance* value of *Dilate/Erode* nodes, but there are no input sockets.

I know it can be done with Python script or with Driver, but I want change it only within Compositor.

Comment: Same question is posted 6 years ago. Is there still no solution?
[Why do some values on nodes lack an input socket? - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/why-do-some-values-on-nodes-lack-an-input-socket)

Comment: After reading the above thread carefully, I noticed the contributor had already written the solution. Oops.

Comment: If you, like me, are scouring old threads looking for a solution that works for reusable nodes and can be controlled outside the node group (drivers don't work well for those), you can also use some greater than and mix nodes to create a custom node that acts like a Dilate/Erode node, but with an input socket on the distance node. Tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbRn-AKwvUA Multiple nodes like this can be controlled from a single input with the normal linkages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a *Value node* and use it with a driver.
That counts as within compositor, right? :)

1. Add a *Value* node
2. In value field *RMB > Copy as New Driver*
3. In Distance field *RMB > Paste driver*

[image]

Comment: Great answer @JachymMichal!

Comment: Thanks, thats very kind of you :).

Comment: Wow, it's really simple. Thank you for the great answer.

Answer (score 4):

[image: node group input]

Thank you @JachymMichal! It also worked with input values of node groups.