# Driver in Compositing Node Group doesn't update

Tags: compositing-nodes, drivers

I have the same problem as already described and solved here:

[In Compositor, is it possible to change multiple node values simultaneously even though there is no input socket?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184956/in-compositor-is-it-possible-to-change-multiple-node-values-simultaneously-even)

Unfortunately, the driver does not update for me. I have tried many times, but it does not work.

What I want is to control from the Blur Node the Blur Size with the Node Group Input.

The blur node with drivers:

[image]

The Node Group value:

[image]

The Driver:

[image]

Is there a workaround for this? Or can I get the driver to update each?

Comment: pls show us at least your node tree

Comment: it works for me, but i don't know what you did - so to be sure what your problem is the best would be if you provide your blend file

Comment: Updated the question. I'm afraid I don't see where I can add a .blend file, but with the images it should be much easier to understand.
The driver then works when you add it, but when I make changes in the node input afterwards, nothing happens.

Comment: thanks for clarifying and your screenshots. I wrote an answer. I hope you wanted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hover over your input socket value, copy as new driver, go into the node group, paste it in your value (e.g. x)

result:

[image]

Comment: Oh my god...that's exactly what I did. But when I tried it now, it worked! The reason: Apparently the driver is not updated when the NoteGroup is not connected. This is possibly a bug, I could imagine.... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. It's rather an optimization. If a node is not connected to anything, it is not computer to save on computing time. It just doesn't take into account the fact that the node inputs are animated